# WPF: RibbonControlsLibrary.Luna.dll not found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon

I've used [RibbonControlsLibrary](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en) in my application. In Windows 7 everything was fine, but in Windows XP in the event handler `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` in parameter e.Name I got RibbonControlsLibrary.Luna.dll. Assembly.LoadFrom(e.Name) threw the exception: FileNotFoundException. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't. WPF is looking for the theme assembly associated with he RibbonControlsLibrary. If it's found, then it would load the appropriate Luna theme. Otherwise, it will fall back to the generic theme in the RibbonControlsLibrary.

So your AssemblyResolve, should just ignore the fact that the RibbonControlsLibrary.Luna is not found.